# <textarea> can't post values in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, textarea

Hi I'm new to laravel and I create a form then when I tried to post values with textarea it didn't work and this is my code for form:

```
<form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" id="contactForm" action="{{route('newPage')}}">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" data-aos="zoom-in">
    <div class="form-group ">
        <label for="username" class="control-label">موضوع:</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="username"
        value="{{ Request::old('title') ?: ''}}">
        @if ($errors->has('title'))
          <span class="help-block">وارد کردن موضوع ضروری است</span>
        @endif
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>

  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" data-aos="zoom-in">
    <div class="form-group ">
        <label for="contents" class="control-label">سرفصل مربوطه به انگلیسی:</label>
        <input type="text" name="related_subject" class="form-control" id="username"
        value="{{ Request::old('related_subject') ?: ''}}">

        @if ($errors->has('related_subject'))
          <span class="help-block"> وارد کردن سرفصل ضروری است</span>
        @endif
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>

  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" data-aos="zoom-in">
    <div class="form-group ">
        <label for="contents" class="control-label">شرح مطلب:</label>

        <textarea type="text" rows="10" cols="100" name="contents"
           class=
          "form-control" id="message" style="resize:none"></textarea>

        @if ($errors->has('contents'))
          <span class="help-block"> وارد کردن سرفصل ضروری است</span>
        @endif
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>

  <div class="col-lg-12" data-aos="zoom-in">
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign up</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
    </form>
```

but it works when I use input instead of textarea! I mean when I deleted text area and use an input it works correctly!
How can I solve it?

Comment: Can we have a look at the `<form>....</form>` ? Just posting the `textarea` leaves us in so many questions.

Comment: Its too long how can I send it for you?

Comment: Please update the question with the code or put it up on pastebin and provide a link here.

Comment: There is no 'type' property for text area where you have used type='text'

Comment: Are you getting value for other form elements within your controller

Comment: No I just want to save values in data base.

Comment: this is part of  my controller:
   public function postNewPage(Request $request)
   {
    
     Page::create([
       'title' => $request->input('title'),
       'related_subject' => $request->input('related_subject'),
       'contents' => $request->input('contents'),
       'position' => $request->input('position'),
       'visible' => $request->input('visible'),
     ]);

     return redirect()
     ->route('admin.lord')
     ->with('info', 'Your account has been created');

   }

Answer (score 1):

You have issue in your textarea syntax

your code

```
<textarea type="text" rows="10" cols="100" name="contents"
       class=
      "form-control" id="message" style="resize:none"></textarea>
```

normal code for textarea

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="100" name="contents"
       class=
      "form-control" id="message" style="resize:none"></textarea>
```

textarea has no **type** for more detail you can visit

-[W3School html textarea section give you more detail](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp)

Comment: are you sure kindly give more details about your code 

like form tags what you are using and controller how you get the form request on the controller ?

Comment: if you want I can send you the controller.

Comment: @SAM I hope your issues are fixed if not then let me know and send me the file of controller

Comment: I found the problem but I don't know how to fix it. I'm using a bootstrap template and in it's js folder there is a file: jquery.min where every time I delete this file my textarea works fine! but with that my textarea doesn't work!

Comment: @sam :/ its seems you are using ajax method to perform this form and you have more than one jquery file in your templates that's its happened inspect your code and check do you have jquery twice?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have submitted form use javascript with form's id.
So you should add [form] attribute that same id of form to textarea.

```
example:
<form name="frmA" id="frmA" action="/" method="post">
 <textarea form="frmA"></textarea>
</form>
```